# In eclipse how to create a class without a java project?

Tags: java

This is the Question asked in one of the interview...
Usually in eclipse we write class after creating a java project. Is it possible to have a class  without a java project?

Comment: No you can't. How are you going to specify which version of JDK you will need to compile and other settings?

Comment: Why did people down vote this?  It's as clear as can be!

Comment: An IDE like Eclipse needs this project, but Java itself doesn't. You can create a class with a text editor and compile it using `javac`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of creating a class in Eclipse without creating a project first. I am sure you will know how to create a new project but just in case:

File -> New -> java project

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse essentially does require you to create a project and put your Java source code into it.

It's actually possible to just use File | Open... to open a Java file and edit it, but the editor will have reduced functionality; it will act more like a plain text editor and won't be able to help you write code and find errors the way the full editor can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, What you need to do is do FILE ---> New Class -----> (The type the class name). Then add that to a Java Project. Any more question Ask my profile